# How to add a cancel button for google signIn accountPicker dialog box in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-signin, accountpicker

I am new to android. I am trying to make an android application with authentication by google signIn using firebase. I want to add an additional button to the google signIn accountPicker. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    android.app.AlertDialog Dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
        // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso.
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(MainActivity.this, gso);
        signIn();
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Authentication failed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                        }

                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());
        if (acct != null) {
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
            String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
            String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
            String personId = acct.getId();
            Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Name = "+ personName , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the accountpicker dialog of the google signIn.

[image]

I need to add an additional (Cancel)button in this dialog.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you need to add the cancel button, you can click back or outside the box, can't you?

Comment: yeah.. it can be done in that way.But it"s not the answer iam expecting.

Comment: Well, this is not an answer :-P